# why is video not showing for me on discord in this case?

Tags: discord

I went into a "discord server" and in one of the rooms somebody requested somebody else into a "VC" (voice call).

Then a Voice call section opened up in the side bar on the discord server and some people joined and I joined too, and it looks like this.

As you can see if I hover over the user where it says "live", who is presumably the one broadcasting, then I see some stuff. But in their main screen I see nothing.

[image]

Another pic this time without that hover over screen covering anything.

[image]

As you can see the live broadcaster's username "le",  is in two of the boxes.

One of the boxes just shows blue dots moving around. And the other one shows nothing.

So i'm not quite sure what's going on there.

It's not a case where I ask the host 'cos the host just set up the room for somebody that asked him about something . But others have joined and I just joined. So i'm not speaking there.

Any idea why the video isn't showing in this case?

Comment: it works now and i'm listed as one of two spectators, so maybe the host had to add me as a spectator